# Why does the LSTM cell unit need the reuse flag?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I was looking at the tensorflow LSTM tutorial and it had the line of code:

```
    def lstm_cell():
        # With the latest TensorFlow source code (as of Mar 27, 2017),
        # the BasicLSTMCell will need a reuse parameter which is unfortunately not
        # defined in TensorFlow 1.0. To maintain backwards compatibility, we add
        # an argument check here:
        if 'reuse' in inspect.getargspec(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell.__init__).args:
            return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
                    size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True,
                    reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
        else:
            return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
                    size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
```

which seems confusing to me. It seems there is an issue with the re-use flag. Why is it important. Why do we need it? I know RNNs always share parameters as we produce new states, so why would it be randomly be decided to remove such an important flag...which makes me think I might not understand what is missing. I understand very well [Chris's blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) post on LSTM so I find this piece of code in the tutorial really mysterious.